# What is the alternative to using a "summary" attribute of an HTML table for screen readers?

Tags: html, accessibility

Refer to the [table attribute summary in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#attr-summary)

> Usage Note: Do not use this attribute, as it has been deprecated. Instead, choose one of these methods to add a description of a table:
>
> - Use prose around the table (this method is less semantic).
> - Add a description in the table's  element.
> - Add a description in a  element, inside the table's  element.
> - Include the  element in a  element and add the description in prose next to it.
> - Include the  element in a  element and add the description in prose inside a  element.
> - Adjust the table so that a description is not needed (e.g. use  and  elements).

A summary attribute will work for screen readers, but not show on screen.
Since it is deprecated, What else I can use?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `<caption>` element. It serves a very similar purpose to the summary attribute.

`<caption>` is visible by default, but you can [position it off screen using CSS](http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/#absolutepositioning) to make it visible only to screen readers.

Comment: Can´t you just set it to `visibility:hidden`? You can also put it on `<div style="display:none"`

Comment: Both `visibility:hidden` and `display:none` will remove the element from the accessibility tree and hide the content from all visitors. These items will not be available to assistive technology or sighted visitors.